# J Query: Store screen position of draggable DIVs into MYSQL

Tags: jquery

I am completely new to jQuery and Ajax and need some guidance, I have the draggable DIV codes working, but I'd like to be able to store the position of where I move a draggable div to on the screen, so that when the page is reloaded, it will return to were it was left.

Is there a simple to follow example that I can follow?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-eTyxS0rkjpLEo16uXTS0uVCS4815lc40K2iVpWDvdSY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



 <title>Lesson Tracker </title>
  
  




  <style>
.mydraggable {
  width: 150px;
  height: 51px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
  background: silver;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family:    Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:      10px;
  font-weight: normal;
  
  border-style: dotted;
}

h1 {
  color: blue;
   font-family:    Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:      30px;
  font-weight: normal;
   text-align: center;


}


p {
  color: black;
   font-family:    Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:      18px;
  font-weight: normal;
   text-align: center;


}

.button {
  background-color: #008CBA; /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}



  </style>
  <script src="../jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="../jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
  
  <script>


$(function() {
  $(".mydraggable").draggable();
});

</script>



</head>
<body>





    



// PHP Code echo's a DIV with a record from the MYSQL database
    
    
    



    
    
    
 <div class="mydraggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p> MYSQL Database Output here </p>
</div>





 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any jquery ajax -> SQL CRUD tutorial will give the basic steps - just replace form fields with your x/y postion.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery offset function, to get current coordinate of the element

docs : https://api.jquery.com/offset/

here the example :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-eTyxS0rkjpLEo16uXTS0uVCS4815lc40K2iVpWDvdSY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <title>Lesson Tracker </title>

  <style>
    .mydraggable {
      width: 150px;
      height: 51px;
      padding: 0.5em;
      text-align: center;
      background: silver;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 10px;
      font-weight: normal;
      border-style: dotted;
    }
    h1 {
      color: blue;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 30px;
      font-weight: normal;
      text-align: center;
    }
    p {
      color: black;
      font-family:    Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size:      18px;
      font-weight: normal;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .button {
      background-color: #008CBA; /* Green */
      border: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 15px 32px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="../jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="../jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(function() {
      $(".mydraggable").draggable({
        drag: function() {
          var offset = $(this).offset();
          var xval = offset.left;
          var yval = offset.top;
          $('#valX').text('x: ' + xval);
          $('#valY').text('y: ' + yval);
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  // PHP Code echo's a DIV with a record from the MYSQL database

  <div class="mydraggable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <span id="valX"> MYSQL Database Output here </span> <br>
    <span id="valY"> </span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer, don't just dump a block of code and expect everyone to know what you did.